# How can you override Upload.aspx or AllItems.aspx etc. SharePoint 2013 (NOT SP Designer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Does anyone know how to override the code that is executed when a user clicks on "new item".
I want to use a custom template / code, so the user will not have to upload the new file each time the person will create a new document.
Simply skip this section and upload the template file in code behind. 
All of this must bee done in cod, so it can work in every SP solutions. 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "Add document" link on a document library? You can certainly replace upload.aspx with your own code. Allitems.aspx is just an out of the box view and you can replace or modify it based on your need. I will explain the details if you can add more information on what you exactly need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but with previous versions, you were able to define *custom content types*, add them to a *doc lib* and then choose the template as new item.

maybe you want to take a look at this: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/21/how-to-create-a-content-type-in-sharepoint-2013/

regarding your attempt to directly manipulate `sharepoint` internal code,
that's not possible since **microsoft doesn't allow usercode in core components**.

maybe you want to create a `webpart` with a "new item"-button, which of course allows usercode.
`On click` you create a new item, upload the template and redirect to the doclib.

Comment: thnax, i think i have to do the second option here and make a webpart.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness also take a look at workflows. there you can attach a workflow after a new element has been added, and upload the template right after the click.

Comment: I found out how to remove this button at least.
You have to set Toolbar Type="None" inside the xml file for you list/doc-lib definition.

Comment: If this helps you, good one! But keep in mind that `Toolbar Type="None"` only means that the TB is `hidden` and if the user selects an item, the ribbon appears anyway (with the New Item Button)